# is.na() or any alternative does not pick up NA value

Tags: r, na

I have a data set (mydata) where the last row has a missing first value (the class of the column where the value is missing is "character").

Column names:

```
A, B, C, D
```

Values:

```
AAA,10,5,2
BGF,4,7,10
BGF,5,13,8
,2,3,45
```

While preparing the data I used several functions to check NAs:

```
anyNA(mydata)
any(is.na(mydata))

anyNA(mydata$A)
any(is.na(mydata$A))

any(mydata[,1]=="NA")
```

None of them showed "TRUE". Can you please help me to explain that? Doesn't `is.na` work with character variables?

P.S. I know there's a thread with a similar title, but the explanation proposed there (my last line with "==") doesn't work.

Comment: You may need `lapply(myData, anyNA)`. Based on the data showed, it is a blank element `""` instead of NA. In that case, `sum(mydata == "")` It is better to show `dput` of example

Answer (score 3):

There is difference between a blank value and NA value. Try doing this

```
 mydata[mydata==""] <- NA
```

and then check for NA values

```
any(mydata[is.na(mydata$A)])
```